# How to use NodeHandle in callback?

Tags: ros, node-handle

[image: Rosanswers logo]

for example, I declare NodeHandle in main,but it can't use in joyCallback function.
I tried to move that handle to be global variable,but it says that handle couldn't init before than main.

Here is the example:

```
 #include <ros/ros.h>
 #include <tf/transform_broadcaster.h>
 #include <nav_msgs/Odometry.h>
 #include "std_msgs/String.h"
 
 void joyCallback(const std_msgs::String::ConstPtr& msg)
 {
    ROS_INFO("I heard: [%s]", msg->data.c_str());
 
    tf::TransformBroadcaster odom_broadcaster;
 
    double x = 0.0;
    double y = 0.0;
    double th = 0.0;
 
    double vx = 0.1;
    double vy = -0.1;
    double vth = 0.1;
 
    ros::Time current_time, last_time;
    current_time = ros::Time::now();
    last_time = ros::Time::now();
 
    ros::Rate r(1.0);
    while(n.ok()){
        current_time = ros::Time::now();
 
        //compute odometry in a typical way given the velocities of the robot
        double dt = (current_time - last_time).toSec();
        double delta_x = (vx * cos(th) - vy * sin(th)) * dt;
        double delta_y = (vx * sin(th) + vy * cos(th)) * dt;
        double delta_th = vth * dt;
 
        x += delta_x;
        y += delta_y;
        th += delta_th;
 
        //since all odometry is 6DOF we'll need a quaternion created from      yaw
        geometry_msgs::Quaternion odom_quat =      tf::createQuaternionMsgFromYaw(th);
 
        //first, we'll publish the transform over tf
        geometry_msgs::TransformStamped odom_trans;
        odom_trans.header.stamp = current_time;
        odom_trans.header.frame_id = "odom";
        odom_trans.child_frame_id = "base_link";
 
        odom_trans.transform.translation.x = x;
        odom_trans.transform.translation.y = y;
        odom_trans.transform.translation.z = 0.0;
        odom_trans.transform.rotation = odom_quat;
 
        //send the transform
        odom_broadcaster.sendTransform(odom_trans);
 
        //next, we'll publish the odometry message over ROS
 #if 0
        nav_msgs::Odometry odom;
        odom.header.stamp = current_time;
        odom.header.frame_id = "odom";
 
        //set the position
        odom.pose.pose.position.x = x;
        odom.pose.pose.position.y = y;
        odom.pose.pose.position.z = 0.0;
        odom.pose.pose.orientation = odom_quat;
 
        //set the velocity
        odom.child_frame_id = "base_link";
        odom.twist.twist.linear.x = vx;
        odom.twist.twist.linear.y = vy;
        odom.twist.twist.angular.z = vth;
 
        //publish the message
        odom_pub.publish(odom);
 #endif
        last_time = current_time;
        r.sleep();
    }
 
 }
 
 
 int main(int argc, char** argv)
 {
    ros::init(argc, argv, "odometry_publisher");
    ros::NodeHandle n;
 
    //  ros::Publisher odom_pub =      n.advertise<nav_msgs::Odometry>("/odom", 50);
    ros::Subscriber sub = n.subscribe("joy_vel_output", 1000, joyCallback);
    ros::spin();
 }
```

How can I solve this problem?

Thank you~

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/12970/how-to-use-nodehandle-in-callback?/) by [sam](https://answers.ros.org/users/189/sam/) on ROS Answers with karma: 2570 on 2012-02-09

Post score: 3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You must initialize the *NodeHandle* in the "main" function (or in any method called indirectly or directly by the main function). I sometimes declare a pointer to the NodeHandle as global variable to my program and then initialize it afterwards in the main. But it will work as you have it right now.

Regarding the ROS Subscriber, try replacing the declaration of the Subscriber by this:

```
ros::Subscriber sub = n.subscribe<std_msgs::String>("joy_vel_output", 1000, &joyCallback);
```

Be always aware of the namespace of your subscribed or advertised topic. I normally use an absolute path to the topic name, so I would have subscribed to "/joy_vel_output" instead of "joy_vel_output".

---

Originally posted by [abacas](https://answers.ros.org/users/1767/abacas/) with karma: 38 on 2012-02-09

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Lorenz](https://answers.ros.org/users/21/lorenz/) on 2012-02-09**:
The difference is an explicit template type, which is not necessary in your case (it is only when using boost::bind) and a & in front of your function name which should also not make a difference in your case.

**Comment by [sam](https://answers.ros.org/users/189/sam/) on 2012-02-09**:
What's difference between I replace the declaration of the Subscriber with the original post?

**Comment by [Lorenz](https://answers.ros.org/users/21/lorenz/) on 2012-02-09**:
I don't think you should ever use a / in topic names in roscpp because it would make remapping of topics to put them in a namespace (e.g. in a multi-robot scenario) much harder and more inconvenient. Instead, using the default NodeHandle constructor as sam did should be the correct solution.

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

In addition what abacas said about using a global pointer, you can also use boost::bind to to pass additional parameters to your callback.

```
#include <boost/bind.hpp>

void joyCallback(ros::NodeHandle &node_handle, const std_msgs::String::ConstPtr& msg) {
...
}

...

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
...
  ros::Subscriber sub = n.subscribe<std_msgs::String>("joy_vel_output", 10000,
      boost::bind(&joyCallback, boost::ref(n), _1));
...
}
```

Note: the boost::ref is necessary because we want to pass a reference to the node handle, not a copy.

A few important notes on your code: passing a NodeHandle to the subscriber callback to read parameters is fine. Using it for creating publishers might be a problem because publishers take a while until all network connections to the subscribers are up. That can have the effect that nothing reaches the subscribers because the publisher is shut down at the end of the subscription callback, before the subscribers connected. The same holds for a TransformBroadcaster.

I'm not aware of any case where running an infinite loop inside a callback is a good idea. The problem is that callbacks are run from the thread that called spin. Now, if the callback blocks the spin loop is blocked, too. That will break ROS communication until the spin thread runs again.

I believe, in your case you actually want to have a few globals (or even better, put eveything in a class), e.g the transform you want to publish. In the callback, you just set the current transform. In the main function, you then have your loop that always publishes the current tf and calls ros::spinOnce.

---

Originally posted by [Lorenz](https://answers.ros.org/users/21/lorenz/) with karma: 22731 on 2012-02-09

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 6